# Error while trying to invite user in orangescrum

Tags: php

I am getting this error while i try to “invite user”.Hoew to resolve this issue?I could not find an app/config folder and so i created one and put a constants.php file there.But how should it look like?

ERROR MESSAGE:-

> "Make sure that you have done the below required changes in
> app/Config/constants.php
>
> You have provided the details of SMTP email sending options in
> app/Config/constants.php You have updated FROM_EMAIL_NOTIFY and
> SUPPORT_EMAIL in app/Config/constants.php

BTW, i created the app and config folder under XAMPP folder.

I found a copy of constants.php in `c:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\pragmarx\google2fa\src\Support .`

And when i try to browse as said in orangescrum helpdesk website

> http://DOMAINNAME/cron/test_email/?to=emailId

Its give me error like this:

> Provide the details of SMTP email sending options in
> app/Config/constants.php

Comment: The default root folder of xampp is xampp\htdocs\ . So for your case it may be c:\xampp\htdocs . Hence the constants.php should probably be placed in c:\xampp\htodcs\app\Config\constants.php. On the other hand, I am quite doubtful that the constants.php in c:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\pragmarx\google2fa\src\Support is having any relationship with the problem of your case

Comment: I tried that ,creating folders app/config in htdocs and putting the file there.But it did not solve the issue

Answer (score -1):

To edit contastants.php use this command.

sudo vi /var/www/html/orangescrum/app/Config/constants.php